# Why LocalStorage path doesn't change when app is on SD card in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have Xamarin Forms application. I'm using PCL storage to save image from web. Path to this storage (FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage) is:

"/data/user/0/com.MyApp/files"

On my Android phone, when I go to settings->Application manager->MyApp->Storage->Storage used->Change and put application to SD card, path to LocalStorage doesn't change. It is still:

"/data/user/0/com.MyApp/files"

Why it hasn't changed?

Comment: Why would you expect it to?

Comment: I expected that all application files are moved from internal storage to SD card and that LocalStorage path becomes some path on SD card.

Comment: I believe you can use System.IO to write to arbitrary disk locations if you need that, but localStorage always goes to the same place.

Comment: And that place is always in internal storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LocalStorage` folder will always remain the same, it's not dynamic or dependant on where your app is running from.

I suspect it is either a naming thing *or* refers to a similar concept as Microsoft implemented with the local and roaming folders. Local folders are meant to stay on the local device you are running from (but still at a fixed location) and the contents of the roaming folder can be synced across multiple devices or platforms. But this last part is just a guess on my end.

If you want to write to other folders you will have to go beyond PCLStorage and start writing [dependency services](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/). See [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Environment+SpecialFolder/) documentation page for the SpecialFolder enum listing. There is also some useful info on an older forum [post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3773/system-environment-specialfolder) on the Xamarin forum.

*Edit*

Of course we could just see what is going on in the repo code. [Here](https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage/blob/d1b905429d0686ed8dfdf03c26fe83ea3c5857ce/src/PCLStorage.FileSystem.Desktop/DesktopFileSystem.cs#L26) you can see that for Android the `LocalStorage` folder is the `MyDocuments` folder on Android. As you have found out for yourself, that will always map to the same folder. If you want to have something on the SD card, you will have to take care of that yourself.

Comment: So LocalStorage is always in internal storage? It can never be on SD card (even if app is on SD card)?

Comment: Please see my addendum on the answer